# Entity framework relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have one `Student` class and one `Standard` class. For example:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public int StdandardId { get; set; }

    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

 public class Standard
  {
    public Standard()
    {
        StudentsList = new List<Student>();
    }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
  }
```

Now I am storing record like this:

I have some standard entries already in the database. Suppose I have one standard entry which has id 4. Now I am storing student corresponding to that

```
Student s=new student();
s.StudentName="Priyesh";
s.StandardId=4;
context.Student.add(s);
context.savechanges();
```

now I want to return student object back to UI with standard object set but I am getting standard object as null(`s.Standard` is null). Please suggest a solution.

Comment: add the standaard instance to student `s.Standard = context.Standard.findById(4);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the standard object with Id 4 and add the student to it's Students collection and set the Standard object entityState to be Modified, and the new Student should has an Entity State Added, and then save your changes.

this will add the new student and link it to the Standard entity.

So your code will like this pseudo code

```
var standard4 = context.Standards.SingleOrDefault(s=> s.Id == 4);
if(standard4 != null)
{
    var s=new student();
    s.StudentName="Priyesh";

    standard4.Students.Add(s); // this will set the State for Student to be Added
    context.Entry(standard4).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.savechanges();
}
```

Hope that helps.